# Move entry if same text in multiple entry with group-advancement in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I try `group-adjacent` for take multiple entry same text `substring-before(named-content[@content-type = 'emEntry'], ' ')` after move to `e.g. Board of Trustees v Sweeney` before `Board of Trustees of Leland`. Because I want to decedent to `v` string and after `v` string ascending order. I try but my xslt code not properly work.
**Input XML**

```
<root>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">AIG Prop. Cas. Co. v Cosby (CD Cal, Nov. 13, 2015, No. CV 15&#x2013;04842&#x2013;BRO (RAOx)), 2015 US Dist Lexis 174858:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">AIG Prop. Cas. Co. v Green (D Mass 2016) 217 F Supp 3d 415:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">AT&#x0026;T Communications, Inc. v Superior Court (1994) 21 CA4th 1673:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">AT&#x0026;T Corp. v Hulteen (2009) 556 US 701, 129 S Ct 1962:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Blutt v County of Sacramento (ED Cal, Mar. 2, 2006, No. 2:04&#x2013;cv&#x2013;1743) 2006 US Dist Lexis 11099:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Board of Trustees of Leland Stanford Jr. Univ. v Roche Molecular Sys., Inc. (Fed Cir 2009) 583 F3d 832, aff&#x2019;d (2011) 563 US 776:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Board of Trustees v Sweeney (1978) 439 US 24, 99 S Ct 295:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Bradford Technols., Inc. v NCV Software.com (ND Cal, Jan. 4, 2013, No. C 11&#x2013;04621 EDL) 2013 US Dist Lexis 1592:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Bradford v Rmckwell Semiconductor Sys., Inc. (4th Cir 2001) 238 F3d 549:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Bradford v Rockwell Semiconductor Sys., Inc. (4th Cir 2001) 238 F3d 549:</named-content></p>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-adjacent="substring-before(named-content[@content-type = 'emEntry'], ' ')">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                <xsl:sort order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<root>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">AIG Prop. Cas. Co. v Cosby (CD Cal, Nov. 13, 2015, No. CV 15&#x2013;04842&#x2013;BRO (RAOx)), 2015 US Dist Lexis 174858:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">AIG Prop. Cas. Co. v Green (D Mass 2016) 217 F Supp 3d 415:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">AT&#x0026;T Communications, Inc. v Superior Court (1994) 21 CA4th 1673:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">AT&#x0026;T Corp. v Hulteen (2009) 556 US 701, 129 S Ct 1962:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Blutt v County of Sacramento (ED Cal, Mar. 2, 2006, No. 2:04&#x2013;cv&#x2013;1743) 2006 US Dist Lexis 11099:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Board of Trustees v Sweeney (1978) 439 US 24, 99 S Ct 295:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Board of Trustees of Leland Stanford Jr. Univ. v Roche Molecular Sys., Inc. (Fed Cir 2009) 583 F3d 832, aff&#x2019;d (2011) 563 US 776:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Bradford v Rmckwell Semiconductor Sys., Inc. (4th Cir 2001) 238 F3d 549:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Bradford v Rockwell Semiconductor Sys., Inc. (4th Cir 2001) 238 F3d 549:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Bradford Technols., Inc. v NCV Software.com (ND Cal, Jan. 4, 2013, No. C 11&#x2013;04621 EDL) 2013 US Dist Lexis 1592:</named-content></p>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I have Done**

```
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-adjacent="substring-before(named-content[@content-type = 'emEntry'], ' ')">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                <xsl:sort select="substring-before(., ' v ')"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```